# .htaccess path only accessible by ip

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal-7

I would like to block a path from my site using the .htaccess configuration. The idea is that only a specific set of IP's can access that specific path from the URL.

**Note:** It's a path, not a page or directory. We are trying to shield off a web-service so there will be only post calls to the URL's.

I would like the url `example.com/rest` to be blocked and everything behind that url based on IP. So `example.com/rest/test_service` and `example.com/rest/test_service/read` should be blocked.

All other paths from the application should remain functional.

What I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. Not a single page is accessible like this.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/rest$" rest_uri

<RequireAll>
    Require env rest_uri
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    </RequireAny>
</RequireAll>
```

I've tried different things but none of them seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directives like this to allow an IP range for certain URL:

```
# set env variable if URL is /rest or /rest/
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/rest(/.*)?$" rest_uri

Order deny,allow

# first deny all
Deny from all

# then allow if env var is not set
Allow from env=!rest_uri

# also allow your IP range
Allow from 10.1.0.0/16
```

Comment: This does work for the URL /rest and /rest/ but it still allows me to access /rest/foo/bar

Comment: Nope. When checking my ip on whatismyipaddress.com and having set it like Allow from 154.52.XX.XX in the htaccess I don't get permissions to the paths. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check from Apache logs what remote IP is being logged there. For testing you can also write `Allow from 154.52` to allow all the range in `154.52`

Comment: Maybe dumb question, it should be the ISP IP correct? Not the machine IP eg laptop ip address.

Comment: If your web server is on Internet then it will be ISP provided IP. If webserver is on LAN then it will be some LAN IP

Comment: Webserver is a cloud solution so that means I should use the ISP IP but still doesn't allow me in.

Comment: I've tested this solution before posting so I still suspect you're not using right IP.

Comment: So checking the apache logs, when visiting the home page the IP in the log matches. But when accessing rest a different IP is logged. We suspect this being an issue with the loadbalancer and are investigating it further. However your solution is indeed working because we tested it with this strage IP.

Comment: Solved now after consulting our hosting. Thanks

Comment: I'm so glad to learn it is finally working for you. It was indeed a bit tricky problem to solve.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mod rewrite to allow a spacific ip address

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !YourIP$
RewriteRule ^/?rest - [F]
```

This will return 403 forbidden error for all other ip addresses if /rest or /rest/foobar is accessed.

Comment: I can use multiple lines of `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !YourIP$` to allow more IP's? And can I use ranges like this: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24$`

Comment: No, ip ranges can not be used in mod rewrite. You can use multiple rewriteConditions to allow more ips.