# .htaccess basic auth combined with ip restriction

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7

I would like to block a path from my site using the .htaccess configuration. The idea is that only a specific set of IP's can access that specific path from the URL after they authenticated using basic auth.

**Note:** It's a path, not a page or directory. We are trying to shield off a web-service so there will be only post calls to the URL's.

I would like the url `example.com/rest` to be blocked and everything behind that url based on IP. So `example.com/rest/foo` and `example.com/rest/foo/bar` should be blocked.

All other paths from the application should remain functional and without basic auth.

The IP blocking part has been resolved in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002006/htaccess-path-only-accessible-by-ip) I asked.

The basic configuration (the blocking part, there is more in the .htaccess but is not relevant to this question.) you can find below.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/rest(/.*)?$" rest_uri
# Check on what subdomain we are.
SetEnvIf Host ^local\. None_Prod_Env

# Static
SetEnvIf AH_CLIENT_IP ^123\.123\.123\.123$ Allow_Host
# Range
SetEnvIf AH_CLIENT_IP ^123\.123\.123\. Allow_Host

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=!rest_uri
Allow from env=Allow_Host
Allow from env=None_Prod_Env
```

So the configuration above blocks all access to /rest/* but not to non rest paths, it allows a user coming from IP X (Allow_Host variable) and we allow none production environments in this case local.

I tried to extend this functionality with basic auth like so:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/rest(/.*)?$" rest_uri
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "/rest(/.*)?$" require_auth=true

# ... Allow Host stuff and none prod stuff ...

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=!rest_uri
Allow from env=Allow_Host
Allow from env=None_Prod_Env

AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

However this resulted in a basic auth on all pages and not only for the /rest/* url. I played a lot with it but couldn't figure it out. Changing `SetEnvIfNoCase` to `SetEnvIf` also didn't help.

Note: Our server is running apache 2.2.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this complex problem using a combination of few Apache directives i.e. `mod_dir`, `mod_setenv` and `mod_auth_basic`:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/rest(/.*)?$ rest_uri
# Check on what subdomain we are.
SetEnvIf Host ^local None_Prod_Env

# Static
SetEnvIf AH_CLIENT_IP ^123\.123\.123\.123$ Allow_Host
# Range
SetEnvIf AH_CLIENT_IP ^192\.168\. Allow_Host

RewriteEngine On

# block if request is /rest/* and IP is not whitelisted and not localhost
RewriteCond %{ENV:rest_uri} =1
RewriteCond %{ENV:None_Prod_Env} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:Allow_Host} !=1
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# ask auth for /rest/* && NOT localhost && whitelist IP
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=!rest_uri
Allow from env=!Allow_Host
Allow from env=None_Prod_Env
Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and add `satisfy any` to your code. Give it a try this way.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/rest(/.*)?$" rest_uri
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://local\.example\.com/" None_Prod_Env

AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=!rest_uri
Allow from env=Allow_Host
Allow from env=None_Prod_Env
Satisfy any
```

Comment: That would make it partially work, it would show the auth screen while not being on the whitelisted IP, but if you are on a whitelisted IP it doesn't show the auth, which it should do.

Comment: So you want both auth and valid IP? you can try `Satisfy all`

Comment: User should be on a whitelisted IP AND successfully authenticated OR he could bypass auth and IP restriction when he is on local.example.com/rest. The first part is currently more important.

Comment: I updated the answer. See if that works. You probably need to be checking the referrer for what you need.